Almost sure convergence of random variables; dependence on $\omega$
Let us for example take the strong law of large numbers which states for $X_1,...,X_n$ defined on a common probability space the quantity
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega)-\mu\right|=0
$$for almost every $\omega$. The definition of almost sure convergence seems to imply for almost every $\omega$, and for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n(\omega,\varepsilon)$ for which $$
\left|\frac{1}{n(\omega,\varepsilon)}\sum_{i=1}^{n(\omega,\varepsilon)} X_i(\omega)-\mu\right|<\varepsilon.
$$
1.) Am I interpreting this correctly, i.e. should my $n$ depend on $\omega$?
2.) Purely from the almost sure convergence of the law of large numbers, can I conclude directly from this statement that for every $\varepsilon>0$ then for $n$ sufficiently large, with probability 1 we have$$
\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega)-\mu\right|<\varepsilon?
$$


YES 2) NO. How large should $n$ be depends on $\omega$

